# Using Youtube API to find videos with zero views

Tags: api, youtube

I have been trying to use the Youtube API to fetch videos with zero views, and I have not had much luck.

It is my current impression that I can fetch videos made in the last day, and then sort them in descending order, but this does not help much.

Has anyone attempted to do this before, and could you point me in the correct direction?

Comment: There is no specific way to only retrieve videos with no views via YouTube's API. You are on the right track though. Take a look at [Zero Views](http://zeroviews.net/), [Underviewed](http://underviewed.com/), and [Petit tube](http://www.petittube.com/) for some insight on how they accomplish this. *Disclosure: I'm the developer of Zero Views*

Comment: Okay... So I see how Underviewed does their site by searching for videos whose names match common file names, but I am still not quite sure how petit tube and zero views work.  The problem I am having is that I can only fetch 50 videos at a time with Search: list and that is not nearly enough videos..... Any other hints?